# RASA Entity Intent Extraction from Custom Data using DIETClassifier

Tags: python, chatbot, named-entity-recognition, rasa, rasa-nlu

I want to build a Q&A chatbot using Rasa. I have text to be used for training extracted as a list of strings from various articles. How can I use `DIETClassifier` for extracting entities and intents from this data through `RASA`?

Comment: rasa community is not so very helping

Comment: you can try this:
https://forum.rasa.com/t/lookup-table-didn-t-work-for-regexfeaturizer-dietclassifier/51092